# Lua audio script for roblox isnt working?

Tags: lua, roblox

my friend made a script for a club game and the audio seems to not work please help

```
local playlist = {4773093598, 727844285}
local mubic = game.Workspace.moosesack
local G_egg = true
while G_egg == true do
    for i, v in ipairs(playlist) do
        mubic.SoundId = v
        mubic:Play()
        wait(mubic.TimeLength)
    end
end
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what is the actual issue? Is no sound playing? Are errors showing up in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to assign multiple Audio ID’s to a single Sound Instance at one time?

To create a functioning music playlist, you would need to create a queue.

And also, because you are using a `while` loop you are exhausting the Lua thread processor, you would need to add `wait()`.
Furthermore, the while loop is an actual loop, so it will execute the same code infinitely until your boolean switches to false.

Answer (score 0):

From the information that you've given ("seems to not work"), there is 1 error in your code.

> `mubic.SoundId = v`

What the code is being read as is "mubic.SoundId = 4773093598"

To roblox, this is not correct as the SoundId must be defined as a string and as an asset id.  Your code should look like:

```
local playlist = {4773093598, 727844285}
local mubic = game.Workspace.moosesack
local G_egg = true
while G_egg == true do
    for i, v in ipairs(playlist) do
        mubic.SoundId = "rbxassetid://"..tostring(v)
        mubic:Play()
        wait(mubic.TimeLength)
    end
end
```